# Smarthseet API List single sheet (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, smartsheet-api

In the Smartsheet API (Python SDK), there is a way to list all sheets (returns an IndexResult object)

```
list_sheets()
```

and ways to get a single sheet (returns a Sheet object)

```
get_sheet()
```

or

```
get_sheet_by_name()
```

What I want to do is get the information like ownerInfo or source from a single sheet. Which would have a larger impact -- listing all sheets (I have a lot of them) and extracting the one sheet of concern or getting the sheet of concern and extracting the info from it?

Or does it not matter at all.
Or am I overthinking this? It **feels** like GET is more intrusive that LIST, but  I don't know that for sure.

Thanks

Craig

Comment: Are you getting the source or ownerInfo for a batch of sheets, or are you trying to get it for a single sheet at a time?

Comment: One sheet or maybe a handful (like those in a Workspace). The initial use case was a single sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the sheet you're looking for, making a request for that individual sheet will be a much smaller request. Particularly if you have thousands or tens of thousands of sheets, getting the list of all of them could be quite intensive. Requesting an individual sheet will include extra data you're not looking for, like the actual grid data, but overall this will be much smaller.

Comment: Thanks. That was my assumption, but wanted to be sure. I think I'll pick some arbitrary number and if more than that, use the list, otherwise, get them individually.